# Remove CSS from an element when that element isn't available in a Tumblr theme?

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr

I'm building a tumblr theme and have padding applied to my list of notes on the permalink page.

When the list of notes is enabled and there are reblogs/likes for the post it displays the list as intended with padding top and bottom. My issue is when the list of notes is enabled but there are no notes for that post the gap created by the padding is still visible so its creating a gap that shouldn't be there.

I wondered if there is a solution to this? I'm pretty sure there must be, but I just can't get my head around it.

An example of the gap being created is here between the like/reblog buttons and the disqus box.

http://minori-theme.tumblr.com/post/104674196686/melbourne-based-photographer-brooke-holms

HTML

```
{block:IfShowNotesList}
 {block:PermalinkPage}
<div class="f-all e-all d-all b-all a-all">
    <section class="f2-f4 e2-e4 d3-d4 b4-b5 a4-a5">
                <ul class="postListNotes">
            {block:PostNotes}
                {PostNotes}
            {/block:PostNotes}
                </ul>
    </section>
</div>
{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:IfShowNotesList}
```

CSS

```
{block:IfShowNotesList}
    ul.postListNotes {padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 80px;}
{/block:IfShowNotesList}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{block:****}` tags are created exactly for this purpose: to display markup only when `****` exists.

Use this code to hide the `ul` element if there are no notes to display:

```html
{block:PostNotes}
    <ul class="postListNotes">
        {PostNotes}
    </ul>
{/block:PostNotes}
```

You can hide the rest of the elements too:

```html
{block:IfShowNotesList}
    {block:PostNotes}
        {block:PermalinkPage}
        <div class="f-all e-all d-all b-all a-all">
            <section class="f2-f4 e2-e4 d3-d4 b4-b5 a4-a5">
                <ul class="postListNotes">
                    {PostNotes}
                </ul>
            </section>
        </div>
        {/block:PermalinkPage}
    {/block:PostNotes}
{/block:IfShowNotesList}
```

Comment: I thought this but got myself confused. Thats done the trick thank you so much for explaining this clearly.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Use the [empty](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_empty.asp) CSS3 property:

```
ul.postListNotes:empty {
    padding: 0;        
}
```

or even:

```
ul.postListNotes:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

If the code:

```
{block:PostNotes}
{PostNotes}
{/block:PostNotes}
```

produces anything else of blank or html comments, the :empty selector will not work

In this case, if you can, apply a class, let's say `.noNotes` on `ul.postListNotes` every time there are no notes to display and use this rule:

**EDIT**

```
ul.postListNotes.noNotes {
    padding: 0!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions I've tried both but can't seem to get it working. I'm wondering if I'm putting it in the wrong place. Although I've tried inside and out of the {block:If}

Comment: The padding is applied to ul.postListNotes and I'm pretty sure thats whats causing the gap. What do you mean exactly about the {block:PostNotes}?

Comment: I am not very familiar with tumblr. You use a code inside ul.postListNotes that loads the notes. If that code ({block:PostNotes}) produses any HTML elements the :empty selector will not work

Comment: I see when I inspect the element in my browser it shows a height of the container as 130px which totals to the amount of padding applied to that element. Therefore I don't think it does produce any HTML elements however I've still had no luck getting it to work.

Comment: Try adding ul.postListNotes.noNotes {padding:0!important} see my EDIT

Comment: Thanks but still no joy - would you mind checking the page I linked too. I'm wondering if my browser has cached the theme and is taking a while to update. Also Ive put ul.postListNotes.noNotes underneath the ul.postListNotes {padding-top:50px...} is this the correct order?

Comment: It works fine for me (check img). Clear you cache and make sure that the css rules do not overwrite each other

Comment: I've tried in different browsers and cleared my cache and its not working. Thanks for all your help though.